# To handle Window.open in request Scope in jsf

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am using JSF 1.2 here i have a managed bean in request scope, my scenario is to open a seperate window.  After action is performed oncomplete i am opening a new window since the managed bean in request scopes the values are not populated in new window. Because new object is being created while opening a new window. i can use session scope but that is restricted.

kindly help me in resolving this.

Comment: should we assume you use richfaces?

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

- use `<rich:modalPanel>` instead of a new window. Actually, `window.open(..)` should be even more restricted than session-scope (pop-up blockers would not allow the window to open)
- use a conversation scope. [MyFaces Orchestra](http://myfaces.apache.org/orchestra/index.html) provides such scope.

Comment: I am using richfaces but modalpanel will override the main window

Comment: so what? what is going to be inside that window? And are you considering that pop-up blockers will not allow opening?

Answer (score 1):

how about using `a4j:keepalive` to keep the request scope bean alive in the new page.
however for this to work i think your bean must implement `Serializable` interface.